# HTML5 touchmove will always get interrupted on Android

Tags: html, html5-canvas, touch, dom-events, touchmove

(not tested on iOS / Windows phone)

I'm building an HTML5 game for mobile and want to use the user's touch input as a joystick/controler but every touchmove scripts I found out there seem to break after a prolonged touchmove. I've only properly tested this on android devices but I've tried several different browsers and the results are the same. I know of `e.preventdefault` and `width=device-width` and I am using both but this bug still occurs. Here's the code I'm using:

```
function initInput()
    {
        canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");

        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);        
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",mouseXY, false);

        canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", touchDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchend", touchUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchleave", touchUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", touchXY, false);

    }       

    function mouseUp(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        mouseIsDown = 0;
    }

    function touchUp(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        mouseIsDown = 0;
    }

    function mouseDown(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        mouseIsDown = 1;
        touchInitX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        touchInitY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    }

    function touchDown(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        mouseIsDown = 1;
        var touch = e.targetTouches[0];

        if (e.touches)
        {
            if (e.touches.length == 1)
            {
                touchInitX =  touch.pageX - touch.target.offsetLeft;
                touchInitY =  touch.pageY - touch.target.offsetTop;
            }   
        }
    }

    function mouseXY(e)
    {
            e.preventDefault();
            canvasX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            canvasY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    }

    function touchXY(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var touch = e.targetTouches[0];

        if (e.touches) {
            if (e.touches.length == 1)
            {
                canvasX = touch.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                canvasY = touch.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here are a few examples where you can test this behavior happening:

http://jsfiddle.net/B5wgb/8/

http://www.onlywebpro.com/demo/gamedev/mouse_detect.html

These are different approaches/scripts I found on the web and so far all touchmove code examples I found out there none seems to work properly. If you simulate a continuous dragging on android devices touchmove will break at some point and return a touchend followed by a touchstart continuously until you release your finger to stop the touchmove. This can take 1 second or a couple of minutes but touchmove will always break at some point.

Any suggestions/solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a common hardware?/software? issue in the Sony xperia Z series which makes the touch input buggy.